# NoneType has no attribute Append

Tags: python, google-app-engine, syntax

I'm new to Python. I can't understand why a variable is `None` at a certain point in my code:

```
class UsersInRoom(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        room_id = self.request.get("room_id")
        username = self.request.get("username")
        UserInRoom_entities = UserInRoom.gql("WHERE room = :1", room_id).get()
        if UserInRoom_entities:
            for user_in_room in UserInRoom_entities:
                if user_in_room.username == username:
                    user_in_room.put() # last_poll auto updates to now whenenever user_in_room is saved
        else:
            user_in_room = UserInRoom()
            user_in_room.username = username
            user_in_room.put()
            // error here, on line 160
            UserInRoom_entities = []
            UserInRoom_entities.append(user_in_room)

        # name is `user_at_room` intead of `user_in_room` to avoid confusion    
        usernames = [user_at_room.username for user_at_room in UserInRoom_entities]
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(usernames))
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 507, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "path\to\chat.py", line 160, in get
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

How is this possible? I'm setting `UserInRoom_entities = []` immediately before that call. Or is something else the `None` in question?

**UPDATE:** This code works:

```
class UsersInRoom(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        room_id = self.request.get("room_id")
        username = self.request.get("username")
        UserInRoom_entities = UserInRoom.gql("WHERE room = :1", room_id).get()
        if UserInRoom_entities:
            for user_in_room in UserInRoom_entities:
                if user_in_room.name == username:
                    user_in_room.put() # last_modified auto updates to now whenenever user_in_room is saved
        else:
            user_in_room = UserInRoom(room=Key(room_id), name=username)
            user_in_room.put()

            UserInRoom_entities = []
            UserInRoom_entities.append(user_in_room)

        # name is `user_at_room` intead of `user_in_room` to avoid confusion    
        usernames = [user_at_room.name for user_at_room in UserInRoom_entities]
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(usernames))

class ChatRoom(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
    message_contents = db.StringListProperty()
    message_users = db.StringListProperty()

class UserInRoom(db.Model):
    room = db.ReferenceProperty(ChatRoom)
    name = db.StringProperty()
    last_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the same line? Can you validate it?

Comment: Are you sure the indentation is correct? It looks good here but maybe it is different in your real code.

Comment: @Felix PyDev tells me the indentation is fine
@Noufal actually it's two lines before the `.append()` call. This increases me confusion even more.

Comment: @Rosarch - what file is this sample from?

Comment: Is the UserInRoom instance initialized properly? I am not familiar with the GAE data model, but I could imagine that the put()ing the instance would require that the room attribute was set, if there is a relationship between UserInRoom and Room (assuming a Room class exists).

Comment: Check your indentation again and be sure that you are not mixing tabs and spaces. Seems like `UserInRoom_entities.append(user_in_room)` is outside the `else` *suite*.

Answer (score 3):

Since it appears that my comment to the question had the answer to this, I'll repeat it as an answer, with the hope of gaining some reputation points:

Is the `UserInRoom` instance initialized properly? I am not familiar with the GAE data model, but I could imagine that the `put()` ing the instance would require that the `room` attribute was set, if there is a relationship between `UserInRoom` and `Room` (assuming a `Room` class exists).

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you're not the one raising exception, you can do something like:

```
            UserInRoom_entities = []
            # raised? then your .append is missing otherwise something else is wrong
            UserInRoom_entities.append
            UserInRoom_entities.append(user_in_room)
```